# Copy uploaded image to my physical directory in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a user profile for my website and I need to allow user to upload his image to be his profile picture, I used the ASP.net upload control and I need to copy the image he uploaded to a physical directory called Images on the server.

Does any one has idea if that is possible using ASP.net?

Comment: post your sample of the upload code method() thanks

Comment: I didn't write any code yet for the upload I just want to investigate first if it is possible?

Comment: of course it's possible you are using .NET correct.. also what version of the framework are you using just curious

Comment: yes I'm using .NET framework 3.5, thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uploading files is possible using ASP .NET.

The [Uploading Files in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) documentation on MSDN should give you enough information to get started.  The example should work fine in later versions of ASP .NET using Webforms.